# Obscure IndexOutOfRangeException in .NET 4

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception

I have an IndexOutOfRangeException that I can not reproduce in debug mode, according to the stack trace from where the exception is thrown it's occurring on the line "return true;" No array indexing on that line, and not even any array indexing in the procedure the exception is apparently being throw in. So I'm guessing the stack trace might be a bit of a red herring.

Does anyone know what might cause this behaviour? I do have multiple threads accessing the object in which the exception is being thrown, but they are only reading from the object, there are no modifications being made. Might this still be a problem?

Any pointers as to where I should start looking to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: A full stack trace or .ToString() is necessary for this one

Comment: Why do you have multithreading as a tag?

Comment: Did you try a "Clean" and "Complete Rebuild".  The difference in behavior between debug and release and the fact the stack trace indicates a line that is not an array indexing line would suggest that debug info in not in sync with your release version.

Comment: What makes you say it's excepting on the line `return true"?

Comment: Kieren - I'm already pulling out the full stack trace. Daniel - because I think it might be threading related. I've done a complete rebuild to no avail, I've been looked into this for several days. The stack trace is reporting the line number as being a line the says 'return true'

Comment: @Will: Without seeing the stack trace, there's no real way to help here...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a local copy before iterating, or find a way to lock collection before iterating.

[A fairly easy read on threading usage in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

(Oftentimes, it's the next line after the actual line that throws exception is shown in debugger.)

Comment: The collection is a 300MB lookup table, so making multiple copies isn't ideal. I can try locking but it gets hit thousands of times per second, so I was trying to avoid the overhead. Do I need locking if I'm just reading from the collection?